# Improving query cost with OR logical operator

Tags: oracle, query-optimization

```
update employee set name = 'TEST'
where  dept = 'TEST.35'
and    id = 3314170573
and    deleted <> 1
and    not exists
       ( select 1 from employee
         where  dept = 'TEST.35'
         and    deleted = 0
         and    id <> 3314170573
         and    (assoct_id = 'A1' or virtual_id = 'V1') );
```

Cost of this query is coming as 16 but query without OR is coming as 10 can someone please help optimising this query.

Comment: why don't you directly make your where condition : `where dept = 'TEST.35' and id = 3314170573 and deleted <> 1 and assoct_id != 'A1' and virtual_id != 'V1'`

Comment: because i want that ASSOCT_ID or VIRTUAL_ID is unique for a particular dept, and adding 'here dept = 'TEST.35' and id = 3314170573 and deleted <> 1 and assoct_id != 'A1' and virtual_id != 'V1'' will check only for the id and not for all records for a dept.

Comment: I wouldn't get too distracted by the cost. Is there an actual tuning issue, or is this just about the number reported by `explain plan`? I never look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your query as following:

```
 update  employee e
    set name = 'TEST' 
  where dept = 'TEST.35' 
    and id = 3314170573 
    and deleted <> 1
    and not EXISTS (select 1 from employee e2
                     where e2.dept = e.dept
                       and e2.deleted = 0 
                       AND e2.id <> e.id
                       AND e2.ASSOCT_ID = 'A1')
    AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from employee e2
                     where e2.dept = e.dept
                       and e2.deleted = 0 
                       AND e2.id <> e.id
                       AND e2.VIRTUAL_ID = 'V1')
```

This will not speed up your query very well, but queries with bind variables could be reused from the database without parsing them again.

Furthermore you can see that indices on the columns (dept, deleted, assoct_id, id) and (dept, deleted, virtual_id, id) will speed up the query, as then the exists validation can be done by simple index range scans.

Also an index on the columns (dept, id) will help speed up the main where.

Comment: i don't think this query is correct. i want Virtual_Id or ASSOCT_ID to be unique across dept.

Comment: It's just a rewrite of your query. Based on simple bool logic `NOT (A OR B)` = `(NOT A) AND (NOT B)` and the fact that `EXISTS(...WHERE (A or B))` = `EXISTS(... WHERE A) OR EXISTS(... WHERE B)` it has to be the same. If it's not correct then your original query is not as well...

Comment: How is this better than the OP's code? You double the NOT EXISTS statements meaning you double the scans of the table.

Comment: To be honest, oracle often does the same in background, when executing queries as the above. It is more to show, of which indices the query will benefit, as the query is more or less optimal as it is. And doing 2 index scans is faster then doing 1 table scan, as index scan is O(log(n)) and table scan is O(n).